Google Sheet Import XML Formular, Webscrapping Categorie ID
I need assistance with creating an import XML formula. I have a URL that changes partially, and it contains a hidden category ID that varies depending on the article. The URL isn’t straightforward but rather a long and complex string. With the unique Identifer


"categoryId":"xxxxxx" (see screenshot)

I can not seem to figure out how to extract only the cat. ID number, as it is not a direct part of the URL but embedded within a longer structure.
I have tried to simply copy the XML path
=IFNA(regexextract(IMPORTXML(B3,"/html/body/script[1]/text())))","[0-9]+")))

and also to assign the clear identifiyer.
=IFNA(regexextract(IMPORTXML(B2,"//script[contains(., 'categoryId')]/text()")))

Also the workaround as in Tab Try 2 , that i first extract the script content and than find the categoryId within the script content, is not giving me the needed result.
=IMPORTXML(B2, "/html/body/script[1]/text()")
=REGEXEXTRACT(C2, """categoryId"":""(\d+)""")

Does anyone have another solution of can see what am I doing wrong?
Thank you
Google Sheet


Here's one approach you may test out:
=let(Σ,tocol(array_constrain(importdata(B2),20,200),1),
 filter(choosecols(split(Σ,":"""),2),left(Σ,10)="categoryID"))



Hi rockinfreakshow,
This is awesome, thank you! However, I now have the following issue: for some reason, my VLOOKUP formula in another column can’t read the entry. Is it possible to implement this in the code so that the outcome is plain text? Otherwise, my workaround right now is to copy and paste the value only and reformat the column to plain text. Only then is VLOOKUP working again.
Thank you so much! :)

recreate this scenario in the test sheet & I can check it out...

Hi, I have changed the sheet accordingly. When I assign the code in E2, to the coloum D2, it can pull the date. However when it is assigned to C2 it wont work

Added to_text() to the existing formula & convert the number output to text form

amazing! that worked. thank you so much
